# how to write this query in joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I want to get all parent category title of child category
so in mysql i can do this with this code

```
SELECT T2.id, T2.title
FROM (
    SELECT
        @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := parent_id FROM `up8te_categories` WHERE id = _id) AS parent_id,
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
    FROM
        (SELECT @r := 8, @l := 0) vars,
        `up8te_categories` h
    WHERE @r <> 0) T1
JOIN `up8te_categories` T2
ON T1._id = T2.id
ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC
```

but in joomla we have API for query
i want to know how can i use that in joomla ?

I know that's somthing like this :

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('title')))
      ->from(......??????......)
      ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__categories', 'T2') . ' ON (T1._id  =  T2.id)')
      ->order('T1.lvl DESC');
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
```

but i don't know how to set from when i want to select again..

what can i do ?

kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to user $query as a string, like this:

```
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();        
    $query = 'SELECT T2.id, T2.title
             FROM (
                 SELECT
                     @r AS _id,
                     (SELECT @r := parent_id FROM #__categories WHERE id = _id) AS parent_id,
                     @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
                 FROM
                     (SELECT @r := 8, @l := 0) vars,
                     #__categories h
                 WHERE @r <> 0) T1
             JOIN #__categories T2
             ON T1._id = T2.id
             ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC';

    $db->setQuery($query);
```